# Converting string of comma-separated items into 2d table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing the following:

```
def make_table(data: str, w: int) -> List[List]:
    pass
```

`data` is a string containing items separated by `,`. Some items may be an empty sequence so multiple commas are possible, the input can also start/end with comma which mean that first/last item is empty.
`w` stands for width and is the number of columns of the output table. We're assuming the input is valid.

Examples:

```
In [1]: make_table("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i",3)
Out[1]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

In [2]: make_table(",,1,,1,,1,,",3)
Out[2]: [['', '', '1'], ['', '1', ''], ['1', '', '']]
```

My first working solution is this:

```
def make_table(data: str, w: int) -> list:
    data = data.split(",")
    return [data[i*w:(i+1)*w] for i in range(len(data)//w)]
```

What I don't like here is that

1. range(len(...)) gives me bad memories
2. I feel like this could be done prettier.

I know numpy could do it, but that's overkill. I'm looking through std libs but don't see anything related.

My second solution is more efficient but a little roundabout, I was looking for some lazy split solution but found only some rejected proposals. I did this:

```
def coma_split(data: str):
    i, j = 0, -1
    while True:
        i, j = j + 1, data.find(",", j + 1)
        if j != -1:
            yield data[i:j]
        else:
            yield data[i:]
            break


def make_3_column_table(data: str) -> list:
    g = coma_split(data)
    return list(zip(g,g,g))
```

But here I don't know how to make zip take arbitrary number of references to g.

How can I improve any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was looking for some lazy split solution but found only some rejected proposals

If you are looking for a ***lazy*** split solution, omit the `list(...)` call in the return statement, and the `zip` object will be returned.

```
def make_3_column_table(data: str) -> Iterator[tuple[str]]:
    g = coma_split(data)
    return zip(g,g,g)   # No list() call here
```

---

It looks like you are looking for the `grouper` recipe of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from more_itertools import grouper

def make_table(data: str, w: int) -> list[tuple[str]]:
    return list(grouper(data.split(','), w))
```

Or without the additional library (and without the fill padding as you assert the data is well formed):

```
def make_table(data: str, w: int) -> list[tuple[str]]:
    return list(zip(*[iter(data.split(','))] * w))
```

Note that the return type is not the requested original `List[List]` return type, but neither was the output of `make_3_column_table(...)`.

Again, if a lazy option is desired with an `Iterable[...]` return type instead of the `list[...]` return type, then omit the `list(...)` calls from the return statements and adjust the return signature.

Answer (score 3):

**Python ranges have a step attribute**. Your first implementation of the
function is on the right track, but you can simplify things further by using
the range to the fullest and eliminating most of your own mathematical
hoop-jumping:

```
def make_table(comma_delimited, w):
    vals = comma_delimited.split(',')
    return [
        vals[i : i + w]
        for i in range(0, len(vals), w)
    ]
```

**You are losing values**. What if the number of values
is not evenly divisible by `w`. Currently, you are throwing
the surplus values away. Is that what you want? If so, just
modify the second argument to `range()`: `w * (len(vals) // w)`.

**Avoid variable re-definition**. Code like this is generally a bad idea. It's
the moral equivalent of changing the meaning of term in the middle of a
paragraph. That undermines readability. And anything that hampers readability
increases the odds of confusion and/or bugs.

```
# What? I was just getting familiar with "data".
data = data.split(",")
```

**Consider the csv module if the delimited string can contain escaped commas**.
For known-to-be-simple delimited data, `str.split()` is fine. For true
csv data, use a proper parser:

```
import csv

def make_table(comma_delimited, w):
    vals = list(csv.reader([comma_delimited]))[0]
    ...
```

**Lazy for the sake of laziness**. If you are committed to
your second approach, you can accommodate the `w` argument
in the following manner. I don't really understand the
purpose of a lazy implementation when the comma-delimited
data is already committed to memory, but perhaps I'm
overlooking a valid use case:

```
def make_table(comma_delimited, w):
    g = coma_split(comma_delimited)
    gen = (g for _ in range(w))
    return list(map(list, zip(*gen)))
```

Comment: love the comment for re-definition :D, variable names makes more sense too. Do you think the 2nd approach is dead end?

Comment: @Kazz Yes, I ignored the second approach: it involves too much algorithm for such a simple task.

Comment: @Kazz That said, it's not a dead end, as shown above.